# Not able to connect to JProfiler

Tags: jprofiler

I am not able to connect with JProfiler 7.2.2 successfully.

In my application, they have a instrumented startup code used in Linux box. I have added `-agentpath:/opt/jprofiler7/bin/linux-x64/libjprofilerti.so=port=8849,nowait` to startup code.

I am seeing the below details in the startup log:

```
JProfiler> VM initialized
JProfiler> Hotspot compiler enabled
JProfiler> WARNING: Dangerous VM parameters detected: [-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC]
JProfiler> The profiling interface of the JVM might crash for certain operations
Setting system properties.
[MySystemClassLoader@4506411] warning javax.* types are not being woven because the weaver option '-Xset:weaveJavaxPackages=true' has not been specified
Starting MyApp
```

But when I connect from a remote client from my Windows PC, it hangs for a while and times out.

Also, the below params are present in the startup params:

```
-Xmx4096m                             \
-XX:PermSize=512m                     \
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m                  \
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError       \
-XX:HeapDumpPath=/opt/CSCOlumos/crash \
-XX:ThreadStackSize=256               \
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC               \
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=5               \
-XX:NewRatio=2
```

Could any of these params cause problem for JProfiler connection?

Comment: You should definitely remove `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` for profiling, however, that is not related to the connection issue. Are tehre no further lines prefixed with "JProfiler>" in the log file when you connect with the JProfiler GUI? In that case, the host name or the port number are probably wrong in the remote session in JProfiler or there's a firewall in between.

Comment: I suggest to read this topic [how-to-run-jprofiler-from-windows-machine-to-remote-linux-jvm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014744/how-to-run-jprofiler-from-windows-machine-to-remote-linux-jvm)